# How can I make a changing information square in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a div on my site that looks a little like the image attached below. It’s essentially a square on the webpage with a list of items on the left, and as the user clicks on these items the information displayed on the right matches the selection. The background color of the selected item and the shown on the right should match.

Any tips? What is this called and how can I further research it? What HTML attributes or CSS styles can I use to make this work? Or do I have to use Javascript? Thank you very much

I tried troubleshooting the web but I couldn’t describe my issue in words; the best I could do was a drawing. Anything and everything is appreciated (especially code!)

Image of the feature I'm trying to do(https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEUrW.jpg)
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "I tried troubleshooting the web "? You should share the code you've tried; SO isn't a code-writing service.

Comment: Please see [ask]. And whomever upvoted this please identify yourself

Comment: This looks like tabs. There are many plugins you can use to implement this.

Comment: Perhaps this is just a left side navigation? that can be done very simply with modern HTMLS and CSS.

Comment: @mykaf I didn’t try any code because I don’t know how to do it. I’m still learning, and I came to SO to learn :)

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss thanks! I’ll look into that and see if it helps. I’ll also check out tabs like another commenter said. Thank you again!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Using HTML, CSS, and JQuery

try this one : [enter link here](https://codepen.io/anu_mistry/pen/oNJMjmW)

```js
$(document).on("click", ".tabseletd", function(e) {
  $("ul").find(".active").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
  $("#tabcontent").find("h1").text($(this).html());
});
```

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
}

.maindiv {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #8080802b;
  padding: 15px;
}

.left-div {
  width: 20%;
}

.right-div {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #8080804f;
}

.active {
  background-color: #8080804f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="maindiv">
  <div class="left-div">
    <ul>
      <li class="tabseletd active">Tab 1</li>
      <li class="tabseletd">Tab 2</li>
      <li class="tabseletd">Tab 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="right-div">
    <div id="tabcontent">
      <div class="content">
        <h1>Tab 1 </h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
.parent {
  background-color: #ff000020;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1em;
}

.section {
  border: solid 2px;
  padding: 1em;
}

.nav-section {
  background-color: #0000ff20;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(1fr, 8);
  grid-gap: 1em;
}

.nav-section * {
  border: solid green 1px;
  height: 2em;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.main-section {
  background-color: #00ff0020;
}

.main-section>* {
  height: 4em;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="nav-section section">
    <div>Many cool links here</div>
    <div><a href="#lake-me">Go to the Lake!</a></div>
    <div><a href="#barn-me">Go to the barn!</a></div>
    <div><a href="#beer-me">Drinks!</a></div>
    <div><a href="#owe-me">$ galore</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="main-section section">Main
    <h1 id="lake-me"> Here we go again we are at the lake! </h1>
    <h2 id="owe-me"> Who am I </h2>
    <h2 id="beer-me"> You brought drinks?? </h2>
    <h2 id="barn-me"> who stole the barn? </h2>
  </div>
</div>
```